# How do I render a Panorama-tracker stabilized 360° video?

Tags: rendering, video

I'm new to blender and I need it to stabilize a panoramic 360° video.
I found this addons https://github.com/dfelinto/Panorama-Tracker
I correctly stabilzed the video and I can correctly see it in the 3D View window but I can't find a way to apply that stabilization in the node editor view so I can't render it. I'm surely missing some steps. I can't understand if I should connect something between Movie clip and Viewer nodes and in that case what I should connect.[image]

---

Thanks guys for helping me. Because of 360 video I need a stabilization that doesn't crop the video or I'll be not able to exactly connect the left and right borders of the image. For this reason I installed the panorama stitcher addons. I need to track two points, set as Focus and Target tracks and It will create a Panorama camera. The correct stabilization is what you can see on top of the screen, that image with yellow curvy line. But the only thing I'm able to get in the viewer and in the file rendering is what you see at the bottom, with the stright yellow line. Even connecting the Stabilize 2D, I had yet tried too, I can't get the rendering like the upper view. I can't find the "Panorama camera" in filters, distort or whatever. I'm stucked here. Here ( https://vimeo.com/75889844 ) he explain how he did it but the missing steps to the final rendering is what I need. Thanks a lot 
[image]

Comment: did you install movie tracking: panorama tracker - add-on?

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect the *image* result of the compositing to the *composite* node as well as the viewer node to see anything in the final render.  The viewer node just controls the compositor backdrop.

Comment: Thanks, but if I can't see it stabilized in the viewer it will not be rendered stabilized. I captured the screeen this to show the discrepancy between the upper stabilized and the final I'm going to render not stabilized. Or am I wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Video Sequencer Editor**, no need of compositing nodes.

After having stabilized your clip, open the Video Sequence Editor, then hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> over the timeline, and choose your clip into the **Clip** submenu.

Then, in the clip's properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) panel, find the checkbox **Stabilize 2D Clip**, located in *"filter"* section:

[image]

Make sure your render settings are set up correctly, according to your needs (resolution, fps, output file and codec...) And finally, just hit **Render Animation** button.

Answer (score 1):

In the compositor add a Stabilize 2D node (Add->Distort->Stabilize_2D) and select the tracked clip to be used for stabilization.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's something with how the add-on sets things up in blender.

Once the add-on is installed and enabled in blender, in the properties panel, under "post processing", you need to disable "sequencer".

Comment: Can you [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/115146/edit) your post and add an image to demonstrate what you mean?

Comment: Yes, good idea! :) I will do it tonight.